# MATLAB: How to make the curly brackets show with legend?

Tags: matlab, legend, curly-braces

I write this MATLAB code:

```
legend('\alpha={1,2});
```

to get α={1,2} but rather I get α=1,2. The curly brackets do not show. How to  make the curly bracket show with legend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

place backslash before the curly bracket

`legend('\alpha=\{1,2\}');`